# Проблема с сортировкой MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

На сайте есть функция обмена сообщениями, я ее переделываю под диалоги. На странице вывожу логины, с которыми уже есть сообщения. Если нажать на логин, то открывается окно с самим диалогом, но для того, чтобы логины не повторялись я использую - GROUP BY.

Проблема заключается в том, что в БД есть поле, отвечающее за доставку сообщения и при использовании GROUP BY это поле перестает работать, т.е если от одного пользователя имеется 3 сообщения и 2 из них прочитано, то последнее тоже из-за группировки выводит как прочитанное.

Как можно от этого избавится? Если убрать группировку, то будет выводить столько логинов, сколько пришло от него сообщений.

Comment: А если для вывода логинов использовать DISTINCT?

Comment: Добавь условие, которое будет отбирать только тех пользователей, в диалогах с которыми есть непрочитанные сообщения.

Comment: если использовать DISTINCT,то происходит тоже самое,
просто нужен список всех логинов с которыми есть сообщения и рядом писалось есть или нет новых

Comment: Происходит тоже самое, потому что вы GROUP BY наверно не убрали.

Comment: убрано, SELECT DISTINCT `from`  FROM messages WHERE `to`='$to'

Answer (score 1):

В самом простом представлении запрос должен выглядеть так:

```
SELECT
    id_user,
    SUM(IF(!is_readed, 1, 0)) -- Кол-во непрочитанных сообщений
FROM messages
GROUP BY id_user
```